# Parse Expect and set output as a string

Tags: expect

Im trying to figure out how to parse the output of a command in expect and then set what it returns as a variable. Basically i have a command output that looks like a list IE:

OneA
OneB
OneB
TwoA
TwoB
TwoC
ThreeA
ThreeB
ThreeC

Basically i need it to find all the values let say that start with One and then run another command with each instance. Something like
 stat OneA and print the output
 then Stat OneB 
 then Stat OneC... 

Hopefully that makes sence.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to use a shell pipeline:

```
send -- "yourCommand | grep '^One' | xargs -L 1 stat\r"
```

In expect, that would be something like:

```
send -- "yourCommand\r"
expect -re $thePrompt
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \n] {
    if {[string match {One*} $line]} {
        send -- "stat $line\r"
        expect -re $thePrompt
    }
}
```